# Displaying a custom progress string on a JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

When `setStringPainted()` of `JProgressBar` is used,the amount of process completion is displayed in terms of percentage.
But how can i customise `setStringPainted()` so that i can display remaining time instead of percentage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setString(java.lang.String)) sets the progress string. If that property is `null` then only a simple percentage is shown. This is pointed out clearly in the documentation:

> ### setString
>
> `public void setString(String s)`
>
> Sets the value of the progress string. By default, this string is `null`, implying the built-in behavior of using a simple percent string. If you have provided a custom progress string and want to revert to the built-in behavior, set the string back to `null`.
>
> The progress string is painted only if the isStringPainted method returns true.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> `s` – the value of the progress string

Comment: Random note: If you found this answer helpful, you can upvote it (the upwards-pointing triangle left of the question). If it solved your problem, you can accept it (the green check-mark left of the question).

Comment: that doesn't help in the OPs requirement _display remaining time instead of percentage_ - setString leads to returning the given text as-is, without any relation to the current value

Comment: Well, time estimation wasn't exactly part of the question as I read it.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly (read: I'm astonished :-) you'll have to implement any value-dependent progress string  yourself, by overriding getString

```
    final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar() {

        @Override
        public String getString() {
            int max = getMaximum();
            return super.getString() + (max - getValue());
        }

    };
    bar.setStringPainted(true);
    ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + 1);
        }
    };
    bar.setString("missing: ");
    new Timer(500, l).start();
```